# create a Dask DataFrame from a Dask Serie of dict

Tags: dataframe, dask, series

Everything is in the question.
When I did this pre-processing part with pandas, I just have to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

serie = pd.Series([{"Event1": 1, "Event42": 1}, {"Event2": 1, "Event5": 1}], name="events")
df = pd.DataFrame(serie.tolist())
```

Now, I have my Dask DataFrame, with a Series containing dict, and I would like to obtain a dataframe, where each column is a key of my dicts.